# Http заголовки - регламентированные знаки пробела, запятые и прочее

Tags: http

Подскажите пожалуйста, регламентированы ли в rfc для http заголовков - знаки пробела, запятых, точек с запятой и прочее ?

Для примера:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Thu, 8 Aug 2021 10:23:13 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=1000
Last-Modified: Mon, 25 Jul 2016 04:32:39 GMT
Server: Apache
```

Вот к примеру "HTTP/1.1 200" - тут пробел между кодом ответа и версией http он регламентирован ? Или может быть два пробела или три ?

Или "Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=1000" - тут тоже строго регламентировано ? Или тоже может быть произвольное кол-во пробелов ? Или может быть пробелы могут быть до или после символа "=" ? Или может быть вообще пробелов может не быть ?

Я не нашел в rfc7230 - по этому поводу.

Comment: `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` это не заголовок, а [status-line](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230#section-3.1.2) (и я вам об этом уже писал вчера)

Comment: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230#section-3.1.2 Вот же английским по белому: версия пробел код пробел описание

Comment: А описание значения заголовка Keep-Alive в RFC отсутствует и представлено только в виде черновика https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-thomson-hybi-http-timeout-03#section-2